# Hi I have tried to connect nats from Ionic on a click of submit button but it is not getting connected

Tags: ionic-framework, nats.io

I have a piece of Nats code which i can run in terminal following by node command but the same can i run in ionic2?

I need to run that nats code in IONIC2 after the click of button

Nats code:

```
submitBtn() { 
  var natnc = nc.connect({'url':'localhost:4222/';}) 
  var subject = "test.sub"; 
  var msg = "Hello World!"; 
  for(var i = 0;i < 100; i++) { 
    natnc.publish(subject, msg); 
    console.log('Published [' + subject + '] : "' + msg + '"'); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: submitBtn()
{
  var natnc = nc.connect({'url':'http://localhost:4222/'})

  
  var subject = "test.sub";
  var msg = "Hello World!";



  
  for(var i = 0;i < 100; i++) 
  {
    natnc.publish(subject, msg);
    console.log('Published [' + subject + '] : "' + msg + '"');
    
  }

  

  




}

Comment: This is what i have tried to run under the action submitBtn()